# MYSQL Remove Duplicates More Efficiently?

Tags: mysql

Although this issue has been brought up in the past, I'm curious if this is still the best way to clean up duplicate entries in a large (3M and growing) table.  After each bulk insert I run this line to keep things tidy, but it's starting to take a very long time to execute.

Duplicate rows can only be determined through 3 columns.  The others either auto increment, have uniqueIDs, sources, etc.

Here's what I currently have going -

```
DELETE n1 
FROM main n1, main n2 
WHERE n1.id < n2.id 
AND n1.col1 = n2.col1 
AND n1.col2 = n2.col2 
AND n1.col3 = n2.col3
```

Any chance I could speed this up, or is this as good as it gets?

Thank you for any help/insight!

Comment: can't you add a unique index to prevent more duplicate rows?

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique Index to your table on columns col1, col2 and col2 like this.

```
ALTER TABLE `main` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `col1_col2_col3` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`);
```

And this will prevent inserting duplicate rows to your table.

For example:
After you insert this values;

```
INSERT INTO `main` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (1, 11, 111);
```

You can't insert this, you will get duplicate row error

```
INSERT INTO `main` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`) VALUES (1, 11, 111);
```

With correct unique indexes you don't have to worry later for duplicate records.

Comment: Hmm...  The only issue I see here is that I need the new duplicate entry to replace the previous record.  `WHERE n1.id < n2.id`  Any way to set this with the unique index you outlined above?  If so, this is really exciting.

Comment: hmm why dont you use Replace instead of insert? replace is nearly like insert. It inserts new record if there can't find a row with that values, or deletes the current one and inserts new. Can this solve your problem? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: But if you need previous records id it will lose because replace deletes old one and inserts new one so identity field counter will change

Comment: the index key cannot be created if col1 or col2 or col3 data type is TEXT or other similar type

Answer (score 1):

Agree with other posters - you can add UNIQUE KEY to constraint duplicates.

If you want to remove duplicates, you can use this query -

```
DELETE t1 FROM main t1
  JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id, col1, col2, col3 FROM main
        GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) t2
  ON
    t1.id <> t2.id AND
    t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3;
```